# Why doesn't this anchor link work in IE11?

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, anchor, internet-explorer-11

What is stopping the following URL from working in IE11, but works in Chrome and Firefox?

http://www.softwareconsole.com/Anchors/default.aspx?pageid=system_requirements&anchor=heading5

HTML:

```
<p>
<span class="heading"><a href="#heading5" name="heading5">Heading 5</a></span>
<br />
Nam pulvinar erat eget magna pharetra tincidunt. Sed lectus ...</p>
```

Comment: Sorry I answered the question and missed the part about the link not working for IE11. I tested the URL you provided with IE11 and everything seems to work fine. What do you see when you click on the link? It may be a caching issue.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue where the fragment doesn't scroll to Heading 5 in Internet Explorer 11, but not in the http://remote.modern.ie build of IE. You can run the remote build from OS X or Windows and confirm for yourself if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the Ampersand (&) is giving you problems depending on the version of IE you are using. Try converting your Ampersands to:

> `&amp;`

instead of

```
&
```

so your URL would look like this: `http://www.softwareconsole.com/Anchors/default.aspx?pageid=system_requirements&amp;anchor=heading5`